# How can you create an empty circle using exclusively CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, geometry

I would like to create an empty half circle in CSS/SASS, here's my code snippet for the half circle, here's the output:

```css
.half-circle{
width: 60px; 
height: 120px; 
border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
background: #15DEA5;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class ="half-circle"></div>
</body>
```

But I want to “empty” it from the inside, here's a screenshot of the result I want to achieve:

[image: This half-emptied circle, yes this is from the video game Geometry Dash]

So is it possible to create an emptied half circles in CSS?

Comment: Do you need it to be actually 'empty' or could it have the same color as the background, or transparent color?

Comment: If you have to stick it to the side you can use negative margin to push it outside the window making it appear it's just half or if it's next to a different element you can use z-index and position to put it behind the other element making it appear as if it's half. The other element has to have a background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 .half-circle {
        width: 60px;
        height: 120px;
        border-top-left-radius: 110px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 110px;
        border: 10px solid gray;
        border-right: 0;
    }
```

HTML:

```html
   <body>
        <div class ="half-circle"></div>
   </body>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0zk8euj9/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circle {
  --height: 200px;
  --width: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  border: 10px solid blue;
  border-top-left-radius: calc(var(--width) * 1.5);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(var(--width) * 1.5);
  border-right: 0;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tanglesit19edu/pen/abVVVMv)